# How can I mark an email as important?

Tags: zend-framework, email, zend-mail

I am using PHP with the Zend-Framework to create emails.
How can I mark the email as important? Outlook will show a red "!" if it is marked right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with Zend, but you are looking for these headers:

```
X-Priority: 1 
X-MSMail-Priority: High
Importance: High
```

According to [this page](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_471.asp) Outlook sets all these headers when you send an Important email, but I suspect that the first one would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

The way to use with Zend Framework is:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->addHeader('X-Priority', '1');
$mail->addHeader('X-MSMail-Priority', 'High');
$mail->addHeader('Importance', 'High');
...
```